# How can I get the email notifications and confirmations to work?

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a form today (free plan) and included a notification email and a confirmation email.  I have submitted 3 entries and have not received any of the automatic responses.  What am I doing wrong?

https://www.cognitoforms.com/GreenvilleTechnicalCollege1/ActionFormForTemporaryEmployment

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever receive the notification messages?
I did a quick check and I do see multiple times where your Colleges Email gateway
delayed accepting messages on 8/7, but appeared to accept the mail later on.

We were seeing a response like this: 

*Remote Server IP:70.150.177.216
SMTP Response:451 4.3.2 Please try again later*

If you are still having problems receiving email just fill out our Write-Us form on our homepage or just click on the "Submit A Support Request" option on our help website https://www.cognitoforms.com/support